# target svg animation "dur" attribute with css

Tags: css, svg

Is it possible to target the "dur" attribute of a svg animate object in css? Would be fun to have things speed up when I change classes of an object, but I can't seem to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

`dur` is not a [presentation atrtibute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute#Presentation_attributes) (*which is what is accessible by CSS*),

It is an [Animation timing attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute#Animation_timing_attributes)

Comment: Moreover, dur is not animatable, so it cannot be changed during animation to speed it up or slow down.